# VBA delete row after added item

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to delete the row below the item added,because once I click confirm sales and want to add more item. the item added will directly replace the row "grand total","gst", and so on. May I know how should I do?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEMdo.png)

Here is my code for add cart :

```
Sub addcart()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, m As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("Sales Point").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Range("C6").Value = 0 = False And IsEmpty(Range("C6").Value) = False Then
       
        'Number of item
        For i = 5 To lastrow + 1
        Cells(i, 5).Value = i - 4
        Next
        
        Cells(lastrow + 1, 6) = Range("C4") 'Item code
        Cells(lastrow + 1, 7) = Range("C3") 'Item Name
        Cells(lastrow + 1, 8) = Range("C6") 'Quantity
        Cells(lastrow + 1, 9) = Format(Range("C5"), "$#,##.00#") 'Unit Price
        Cells(lastrow + 1, 10) = Format(Cells(lastrow + 1, 9) * Cells(lastrow + 1, 8), "$#,##.00#") 'Total
        
        
    Else
    MsgBox "Error Message!!!"
    
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just some comments. It is advised to always use full qualified names when referring to cells or ranges in order to avoid errors later on when the project grows. Have you experimented with using Tables/ListObjects? Adding a row in a table can be done very easily and will automatically move the cells below, and formulas will propagate correctly. Finally I would suggest letting Excel cell format handling the currency formatting, and input numbers in the cells values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
Range("A" & (LastRow + 1)).Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Delete
```

Explanation:

- I believe that the last row equals `LastRow + 1`?
- `Offset(1,0)` is the cell on the next row.
- `EntireRow.Delete` is obvious.